# Get raster from WMS

Tags: polygon, wms, tiles, sentinel-2

I am downloading Sentinel-2 raster files from Creodias.
Several processed polygons are located on two or three tiles at the same time.
I can download all the tiles, make a gluing and cut out the required polygon, but is it possible to get the polygon I need through WMS byskipping the download and gluing step?

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: you can request a bounding box for your area of interest, and all the layers (tiles) of interest, in one GetMap Query, to get one image.